# How do I calculate PCIe 1x, 2.0, 3.0, speeds properly?

Tags: performance, interface, hardware, pci-e

I am honestly very lost with the speeds calculations of PCIe devices.
I can understand the 33MHz - 66MHz clocks of PCI and PCI-X devices, but PCIe confuses me.

Could anyone explain how to calculate the transfer speeds of PCIe?

Comment: Do you need to find the speeds relative to the specification or the actual speed you're getting out of each lane?

Comment: The german [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Technik) has a nice list of speed for each generation, lane count, etc. The [english](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions) one is not so detailed on speeds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand the [table](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Technik) pointed to by Paebbels, you should know how PCIe transmission works. Contrary to PCI and PCI-X, PCIe is a point-to-point **serial** bus with link aggregation (meaning that several serial lanes are put together to increase transfer bandwidth).

For PCIe 1.0, a single lane transmits symbols at every edge of a 1.25GHz clock (Takrate). This yield a transmission rate of 2.5G transfers (or symbols) per second. The protocol encodes 8 bit of data with 10 symbols (8b10b encoding) for DC balance and clock recovery. Therefore the **raw** transfer rate of a lane is

```
2.5Gsymb/s / 10symb * 8bits = 250MB/s
```

The raw transfer rate can be multiplied by the number of lanes available to get the full link transfer rate.

Note that the **useful** transfer rate is actually less than that because data is packetized similar to ethernet protocol layer packetization. 
A [more detailed explanation can be found in this Xilinx white paper](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp350.pdf).